# Java Servlet Not Running Tomcat 8

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat8

I wrote a Java Servlet that has run perfectly on Tomcat 6 for years.  When recompiling the same code using the jdk 1.8 and attempting to deploy this Servlet on Tomcat 8, it will not run unless I remove almost all of the code.  Are there any major coding differences between the two that would cause this software to hangup?
I've looked at the log files to no avail.  No error/exception is provided.

Comment: This sounds to me like maybe it's more of a Java 8 problem than Tomcat 8 problem.  When you say it won't run, are you saying that Tomcat won't even _start_, or does it start, but the code crashes very early?

Comment: Maybe some configuration error? web.xml? server.xml? folder permissions?

Comment: It hangs when I include all of the code.  Meaning that I cannot bounce from one web page to another.  I've removed line by line, and have been unable to narrow down the problem as to why this is happening.  I'm using the jstl, mysql and the normal forward request calls.